# Uninitalized Value Error

Tags: perl

I have program that prints the highest interval every 5 minutes.  I have previously used this same format with another similar array, but I am getting a few errors this time:

- Use of uninitialized value $min in division ...
- Use of uninitialized value $yr in sprintf ...
- Use of uninitialized value in sprintf at ...

  ```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use Text::CSV_XS;

  my %interval; 
  my %month; @month{qw/ jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec /} = '01' .. '12';  

  foreach my $line (@lastArray){          
          $line =~ s/$/,/;
          my ($dow, $mon, $day, $hr, $min, $sec, $yr, $amt) = split /[:,]/, $line;   
          my $key = sprintf "%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d",                 
              $yr, $month{lc $mon}, $day, $hr, int($min / 5) * 5;      
              if (exists $interval{$key}) {         
                  if ($interval{$key}{amt} > $amt) {             
                      $interval{$key}{amt} = $amt;             
                      $interval{$key}{data} = [split ",", $line];         
                  }     
              }     
              else { # first time in this 5 minute interval         
              $interval{$key}{amt} = $amt;         
              $interval{$key}{data} = [split ",", $line];     
              }
      }   
      my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1 }) or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV_XS->error_diag ();  
      $csv->eol("\n");

      # Initialize CSV files  
      open my $fh, ">", 'log_5min.csv' or die $!;  
      open my $FILE, ">", 'last_5min.stat' or die $!;

      # Print Max Busy for all intervals
      print $fh "DayofWeek,Month,Day,Time,Year,rdy,bsy,rd,wr,ka,log,dns,cls\n";
      for my $time (sort keys %interval) {   
          $csv->print($fh, $interval{$time}{data}); 
      }
  ```

The array @lastArray contains the following:

```
Wed,Jun,13,01:00:29,2012,777,23,0,15,6,0,0,2,15,0,0
Wed,Jun,13,01:01:29,2012,782,18,0,14,3,0,0,1,14,0,0
Wed,Jun,13,01:02:29,2012,787,13,0,10,3,0,0,0,10,0,0
Wed,Jun,13,01:03:29,2012,782,18,0,15,2,0,0,1,15,0,0
Wed,Jun,13,01:04:29,2012,779,21,0,12,9,0,0,0,12,0,0
Wed,Jun,13,01:05:30,2012,777,23,0,18,5,0,0,0,18,0,0
Wed,Jun,13,01:06:30,2012,783,17,0,10,4,0,0,3,10,0,0
Wed,Jun,13,01:07:30,2012,786,14,0,6,5,0,0,3,6,0,0
Wed,Jun,13,01:08:30,2012,789,11,0,6,5,0,0,0,6,0,0
```

How can I fix the errors?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: After defining values for `%month`, this code worked for me. Are you sure `@lastArray` contains the values you mentioned?

Comment: @stevenl: I'm sorry I left that part out...just added it.  Yes I am positive that it contains those values.  That is odd that it worked for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Use of uninitialized value $min in division": One of the values in @lastArray has fewer than 3 ":" or ",".

"Use of uninitialized value $yr in sprintf": One of the values in @lastArray has fewer than 6 ":" or ","

etc.

PS - Get rid of `$line =~ s/$/,/;`. It doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

These are not errors, In fact these are warnings.
Either you can remove use warnings; (not preferred though)
or
Initialize any variable before using it.

Here these kinds of error will be shown, if you are assigning undef value to them like that split doesn't have value to put in $min and $yr in list.

So wherever you will use those variable, it will throw warnings.

To remain in safer side, you can initialize those values with null or whatever you like before assigning the values from split. Like my ($dow, $mon, $day, $hr, $min, $sec, $yr, $amt) = ("","","","","","","","");